# How to show Twilio video view in fullscreen in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, twilio

I'm trying to learn Twilio video sdk for iOS.

I implemented the following code to show remote video on a view.

```swift
if let camera = CameraSource(options: options, delegate: self),
   let videoTrack = LocalVideoTrack(source: camera) {

    let bounds = self.remoteViewHolder.bounds
    print("bounds = \(bounds)")

    if let renderer = VideoView(frame: self.remoteViewHolder.bounds, delegate: self) {
        videoTrack.addRenderer(renderer)

        renderer.backgroundColor = .cyan

        self.remoteView = renderer

        self.localVideoTrack = videoTrack
        self.camera = camera
        self.remoteViewHolder.addSubview(renderer)
    }
}

guard let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .front) else {
    return
}


self.camera.startCapture(device: device)
```

The problem is that the video is not showing completely on the parent view(`remoteViewHolder`) of the VideoView(`renderer`)

I went through the official quick start guide but could not find a way to show the video in full screen i.e. cover the parent view completely.

Please see attached screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

How to show the video in fullscreen? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: It looks like the `VideoView` is a subclass of `UIView`, have you tried setting its `contentMode` to  `.scaleAspectFill`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the `VideoView` is a subclass of `UIView`, have you tried setting its `contentMode` to `.scaleAspectFill`?

```swift
renderer.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
```